# Angular does not work with custom html attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-directive, custom-attributes

I have an imported css template written on bootstrap, and want to use it inside Angular app.

**Seems like exactly custom html attributes don't react a loading from router.**

**Application characteristics.** This is a SPA, and all of pages are loaded inside Navbar Component, with corresponding router-outlet wrapping.

**Problem.** Any plugin will render included data only after "mechanical" refreshing page with browser "Reload this page" button. But if I change a src for image, from plugin custom attribute, for example

```
data-background="assets/images/slider_1.jpg"
```

to

```
img src="assets/images/slider_1.jpg"
```

, it will be loaded and shown from the first time.

Example of map plugin. Doesnt show nothing.

```
    <div class="maps-container map-widget m-b-25">
    <div class="map" data-addresses="[4.4, -4.4]" 
         data-icon="assets/images/map-marker.png" 
         data-zoom="16" data-street-view="1">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Example of slider plugin. No background image.

```
  <section class="module-cover parallax text-center" 
data-background="assets/images/slider_1.jpg" 
data-overlay="0.5">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>This is title</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Example of grid item for blog. Here, it should follow masonry style, but renders like strict grid.

```
  <section class="module-cover parallax text-center" 
data-background="assets/images/slider_1.jpg" 
data-overlay="0.5">
```

Comment: Hey Mike,
Were you able to find a solution for this problem? I'm facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

You better use `[attr.data]="name-of-custom-attr"`

This way angular manages the use of custom html attributes correctly.

Comment: Thanks! But those attributes are part of CSS library. How can I change them?

Comment: What kind of plugin is this?

Comment: This is a Boomerand template from Bootstrap Themes from official page. I tried to simply add [ ], but no result.

Comment: Acutually, I had a worde problem before. I used a template from themeforest, and router didnt work. For example, I have a tag with routerLink="/shop", but instead I got redirected to the root. I changed this CSS, and with other is fine. What do you think, why this problems could appear.

Comment: You are not ready to use Angular Framework. Get a tutorial and start from the begining, otherwise the problems will be constant.

Comment: If its not difficult for you, can you say in which part of tutorial? Does this case exist in oficial tutorial from https://angular.io/tutorial?